# perl - using regex to get substring

Tags: regex, string, perl

I do realize that there are a lot of perl regex questions here on SO; I haven't been able to find one that helps me in my situation. I have the following string:

```
string = "dn: example\nl: example\ndepartment: example\nname: example"
```

I am trying to extract each field (except dn) using the following:

```
my ($name) = $output_string =~ /name:\s(\w+)\n/;
my ($department) = $output_string =~ /department:\s(\w+)\n/;
my ($location) = $output_string =~ /location:\s(\w+)\n/;
```

I must not be understanding how to use regex, because that isn't working for me. Each variable is ending up undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `m` flag to switch on multi-line mode, then use start-of-line and end-of-line anchors to match the start/end of the lines in your string:

```
my ($name)       = $output_string =~ /^name:\s(\w+)$/m;
my ($department) = $output_string =~ /^department:\s(\w+)$/m;
my ($location)   = $output_string =~ /^location:\s(\w+)$/m;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is your input; you are expecting a `\n` after `name:` but there isn't one there, and you are looking for `location:` but have `l:` in your input.

Using the `/m` flag and `$` instead of `\n` will fix the first problem, because `$` will match at either the end of a line or the end of the input.